# conditional perfect continuous

Tags: conditionals, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

If he had not supported me, I would not have been standing here in front of you like this.

Is the above sentence gramittically correct or not.

Regards, 
sri.

Comment: Yes. However, your question is not. Please take some help in writing a question. See also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

No I don't think it is entirely correct, and the clue is in the words *here* and *this*, which suggest you are saying it whilst standing there.

In those circumstances one would say:

*If he had not supported me, I would not be standing HERE in front of you like THIS*.

However, if you were reporting your having stood there you could correctly say:

*..., or I would not have been standing THERE in front of you like THAT*.